# Teechart's components of IE can't be showed normally

Tags: activex, teechart

**OS: Windows 7 64-bits**

**RAM: 8GB**

**teechart version: 8.0.0.8**

There are teechart's components in two IE windows.

When switching between each other, some teechart's component of second IE window can't be showed normally.

The unnormal area of second IE window looks like residual image of first IE window.

Example(picture):
[Unnormal area](https://www.dropbox.com/l/FQR8QI1Lyci3g591QEGGTt)

Comment: Can you please arrange a simple example we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Is it helpful if I record video?

Comment: Everything helps but from the screenshot you posted I see this is a quite complex application so it will be difficult to deduce what's going on

Comment: I upload a video in my Dropbox.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23375831/LINE_MOVIE_1414750681060.mp4
Please focus the lower right corner of the video.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I assume there's supposed to be a TChart in that problematic area on the bottom-right, isn't it? However, I see you alternate this problematic page with another page that also has 4 thinner TCharts on it (all in the same column), and this other page show all the TChart without problems, am I correct? Have you checked the differences between these two pages, both having 4 TCharts but only one of them being problematic? To take a deeper look at this here we'd need a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: (1) There's really a TChart in that problematic area.
(2) There's just one problematic page in this case. I also have seen the other page with 2~4 TChart  in the same situation, but someday the error TChart is on the bottom-right, someday is on the top-right...
(3) It is a pity that I don't know how to check the differences between these two pages, but I will pass on this information to engineer.
(4) What can I do for the simple example project here?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course the person who developed the program that is giving problems is probably the person in the best position to minimize that program to the minimum expression still reproducing the problem, so we can reproduce the same problem here and debug it to find the root of the problem easily.